# Is there other solution to use `R.applySpec` without inserting the unchanged keys value?

Tags: arrays, ramda.js

Is there other solution to use `R.applySpec` without inserting the the unchanged keys value?(without needs to type id and name keys in the example, because later the keys will be change dynamically). Thank you.

Here is my input data

```js
const data = [ 
  [ 
    { id: 'data1', name: 'it is data 1', itemId: 'item1' },
    { id: 'data1', name: 'it is data 1', itemId: 'item2' } 
  ],
  [ 
    { id: 'data2', name: 'it is data 2', itemId: 'item1' } 
  ],
  [ 
    { id: 'data3', name: 'it is data 3', itemId: 'item1' },
    { id: 'data3', name: 'it is data 3', itemId: 'item2' } 
  ] 
]
```

And the output

```js
[ 
  { 
    id: 'data1', // this one doesn't change
    name: 'it is data 1', // this one doesn't change
    itemId: [ 'item1', 'item2' ] 
  },
  { 
    id: 'data2', // this one doesn't change
    name: 'it is data 2', // this one doesn't change
    itemId: [ 'item1' ] 
  },
  { 
    id: 'data3', // this one doesn't change
    name: 'it is data 3', // this one doesn't change
    itemId: [ 'item1', 'item2' ] 
  } 
]
```

The solution to get the output using Ramda

```js
const result = R.map(
  R.applySpec({
    id: R.path([0, 'id']),
    name: R.path([0, 'name']), // don't need to type id or name again
    itemId: R.pluck('itemId')
  })
)(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could certainly write something in Ramda like this:

```js
const convert = map (lift (mergeRight) (head, pipe (pluck ('itemId'), objOf('itemId')))) 

const data = [[{id: 'data1', name: 'it is data 1', itemId: 'item1'}, {id: 'data1', name: 'it is data 1', itemId: 'item2'}], [{id: 'data2', name: 'it is data 2', itemId: 'item1'}], [{id: 'data3', name: 'it is data 3', itemId: 'item1'}, {id: 'data3', name: 'it is data 3', itemId: 'item2'}]]

console .log (convert (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {map, lift, mergeRight, head, pipe, pluck, objOf} = R       </script>
```

I'm not sure whether I find that more or less readable than a ES6/Ramda version, though:

```js
const convert = map (
  reduce ((a, {itemId, ...rest}) => ({...rest, itemId: [...(a .itemId || []), itemId]}), {})
)
```

or a plain ES6 version:

```js
const convert = data => data .map (
  ds => ds .reduce (
    (a, {itemId, ...rest}) => ({...rest, itemId: [...(a .itemId || []), itemId]}),
    {}
  )
)
```

The question about [`applySpec`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#applySpec) is interesting.  This function lets you build a new object out of the old one, but you have to entirely describe the new object.  There is another function, [`evolve`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve), which keeps intact all the properties of the input object, replacing only those specifically mentioned, by applying a function to their current value.  But the input to the functions in `evolve` accepts only the current value, unlike `applySpec` which has access to the entire original object.

I could see some rationale for a function combining these behaviors.  But I don't have a clear API in my head for how it should work.  If you have some thoughts on this, and want to make a proposal, the Ramda team is always [looking for suggestions](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/new).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation. Yes, I have tried using `evolve`, and as you explain, it only accept only current value. Once again, thank you.